# How do I get a virtual-hosted–style AWS S3 bucket instead of Path-Style?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm unable to get a **virtual-hosted–style** AWS S3 bucket URL for my static files. As per AWS' [Customizing Amazon S3 URLs with CNAMEs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs), I need to create a bucket with the name **static.domain.com**. But, when I do that and upload a file, the Object URL is a
*Path-Style* URL:-

What I'm getting >> https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.domain.com/testfile.jpg

What it should be >> https://static.domain.com.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testfile.jpg

To get prettier and SEO friendly URL, I'm using Cloudflare and setting the CNAME accordingly, but I can only do that with a *virtual-hosted–style* bucket URL.

I've tried setting the bucket name as *static-domain-name*, but that doesn't work as well. I got the S3 permission denied error S3 couldn't find a bucket named *static.domain.com*.